# Admin mask with custom entity with ManyToManyAssociation

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have an shopware6 admin extension where some custom entity is stored and loaded. This custom entity has a ManyToManyAssociation to another custom entity. In my mask I use a entity multi select component for the selection.

```js
const category = this.categoryRepository.create();
            category.categoryId = this.newCategory;
            category.weight = this.newWeight;
            category.certificates = this.certificateCollection;
            this.categoryRepository.save(category).then(() => {
                this.isLoading = false;
                this.isSaveSuccessful = true;
                this.getList();
            }).catch((exception) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
                this.createNotificationError({
                    message: this.$tc(
                        'global.notification.notificationSaveErrorMessageRequiredFieldsInvalid'
                    )
                });
                throw exception;
            });
```

```html
<sw-entity-multi-select
                    :label-property="labelPropertyCertificate"
                    :criteria="certificateCriteria"
                    entity-name="certificate"
                    :entity-collection="certificateCollection"
                    @change="changeCertificates"
            />
```

When sending the save request the content of my certificate selection is send with and js object with the property id. To create the correct entity I added some Entity creation process and build my own entity collection for the categoryCertificate collection.

Like this

```js
const category = this.categoryRepository.create();
            category.categoryId = this.newCategory;
            category.weight = this.newWeight;
            category.certificates = new EntityCollection(
                this.categoryCertificateRepository.route,
                this.categoryCertificateRepository.entityName,
                Context.api,
            );
            this.certificates.forEach(function(item){
                const categoryCertificate = me.categoryCertificateRepository.create();
                categoryCertificate.categoryId = category.id;
                categoryCertificate.certificateId = item.id;
                category.certificates.add(categoryCertificate);
            });


            console.log(category);
            this.categoryRepository.save(category).then(() => {
                this.isLoading = false;
                this.isSaveSuccessful = true;
                this.getList();
            }).catch((exception) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
                this.createNotificationError({
                    message: this.$tc(
                        'global.notification.notificationSaveErrorMessageRequiredFieldsInvalid'
                    )
                });
                throw exception;
            });
```

The console.log shows this, which would be correct

categoryId: "77b959cf66de4c1590c7f9b7da3982f3"
certificates: r(1)
0: Proxy
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
categoryId: "aa26daab83b04cc6af9a525e7ec1ce16"
certificateId: "8c32fb76000844bcb4d850831fe2f6c1"
extensions: {}
_isNew: true
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
...

The request payload shows this, which is not correct.

{id: "b96c923dcee941c7a05c0cb4f98de4d9", categoryId: "251448b91bc742de85643f5fccd89051", weight: 0,…}
categoryId: "251448b91bc742de85643f5fccd89051"
certificates: [{id: "10fb19bccdb0419ca5f4b7abe6561db2"}]
id: "b96c923dcee941c7a05c0cb4f98de4d9"
weight: 0

where are my categoryId & certificateId properties gone? Does the categoryRepository strip them out?

**Edit solution**

Thx to dneustadt

```js
this.certificates.forEach(function(item){
                const categoryCertificate = me.careHintCategoryCertificateRepository.create();
                categoryCertificate.id = item.id;
                category.certificates.add(categoryCertificate);
            });
```

this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a `ManyToManyAssociationField` the values for the columns of the mapping table are resolved dynamically. Since these columns belong to the mapping definition, not to your actual `CategoryCertificate` entity, they get stripped. You don't need to provide these IDs when you use the respective `ManyToManyAssociationField` property to assign data from either side.